# Apache airflow scheduler not triggering once in a month task as expected

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Here is the dag, which I want to execute on fixed date of every month, as of now I kept it on 18th of every month.
But the task is getting triggered daily by the scheduler. `catchup_by_default = False` is set to false in airflow.cfg file

```
default_args = {
'owner': 'muddassir',
'depends_on_past': True,
'start_date': datetime(2021, 3, 18),
'retries': 1,
'schedule_interval': '0 0 18 * *',
}
```

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

Image 3

[image]

Image 4

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have mentioned `schedule_interval` in your  `default_args`, which is not the way to schedule the DAG.  *default_args* are actually applied to the tasks, as they are passed to *Operators* and not the DAG itself.

you can modify your code as follows, just by removing the *schedule_interval* from *default_args* and passing it in the *DAG instance* as follows and you can set *catchup* flag as *False* to avoid any backfills :

```
# assuming this is how you initialize your DAG
dag = DAG('your DAG UI name', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval = '0 0 18 * *', catchup=False)
```

Comment: Then what could be the reason of triggering it on daily basis?

Comment: on the top right corner of the UI of the DAG, you can see the current schedule it is actually following.